# How can I use Tensorflow with react-native?

Tags: android, ios, machine-learning, react-native, tensorflow

I've looked around the web and cant seem to find a way to use [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) with TensorFlow.

I don't think TF supports react-native (at least not officially) integration but i hope someone in the community has found a way.

How can one use TensorFlow in a React Native project?

Thanks.

---

***CONTRIBUTOR UPDATE**: [Now is possible](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html)*

[image: TensorFlow.js PoseNet in React Native!]

Comment: there is no bridge yet, u should follow this tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

Comment: Now you can, check [this TensorFlow Blog post](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This article explains using tensorflow with native android development.
https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html

I also needs a tf supporting library for react-native. But it seems as you said there is no library yet.

Here they have built an adroid app with react native with tensorflow support, have a look,
https://github.com/NorthFoxz/whatsthis

Comment: Take a deep look, https://github.com/NorthFoxz/whatsthis TF is at server in this example

Answer (score 7):

Came across the following [Platform Adapter for React Native](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-react-native).

> This package provides a TensorFlow.js platform adapter for react
>   native. It provides GPU accelerated execution of TensorFlow.js
>   supporting all major modes of tfjs usage

---

There is also a library [react-native-tensorflow](https://github.com/reneweb/react-native-tensorflow) bridging tensorflow with react-native.

> A TensorFlow inference library for react native.

They have recently added support for iOS, so it's available for both Android and iOS platforms.

To get started:

```
$ npm install react-native-tensorflow --save
```

Perform library link:

```
$ react-native link react-native-tensorflow
```

For iOS you will also need to use CocoaPods with content:

```
target '<ProjectName>'
       pod 'TensorFlow-experimental'
```

There are performance limitations due to the nature of react-native bridge when transferring large data between native side and JS. For other known issues and usage check out the library's documentation.